# ESLint rule to disallow if-else statement in single line style

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

I try to find eslint rule to prevent writing if-else in one line style. What should I expect:

```js
// Wrong
if() /* some code */
else /* some code */


// Correct
if() {
 /* some code */
} else { 
/* some code */
}

// But for if statement (without else) should be correct both
if() /* some code */
if() {
 /* some code */
}
```

Comment: Quite possibly you are looking for this https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/curly

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/curly seems to not have an option for what you want.

Answer (score 1):

With the [no-restricted-syntax](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-syntax) rule you can disallow specific syntax.

Following rule should normally disallow the shorthand if statement.

```
no-restricted-syntax: ["error", "IfStatement > ExpressionStatement > AssignmentExpression"]
```